# How to trigger resending of Google Group mail messages which failed to deliver?

Tags: google-groups

I signed up to a Google Group with an address of my unreliable mail server which has been down for several days. I see in the post overview that mails have been sent to the list, but not to me. How can I get the missing mail in my mail client?

Answer (score 1):

Mails are resend even after > 7 days of idleness of the mail server as soon as it becomes available again.